# How to change cursor for TabItem

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to change TabItem cursor but it changes only when mouse is over a button. The rest of control area still displays 'Arrow' cursor. How to fix that?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="Tab" Cursor="Wait">
            <Button Content="qwe" Height="25" />
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your `Button` in something that will stretch to fill whole available space

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="Tab" Cursor="Wait">
        <Grid Background="Transparent">
            <Button Content="qwe" Height="25" />
        </Grid>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

like `Grid` in this example but note that you'll need to assign `Background` to something like `Transparent` otherwise it won't be hit test visible